# Why you don't create objects in JAVA?

Tags: java, android

I am watching some android tutorials and have one question. Why do you write your class and never create object/use methods like in cpp?

Comment: What do you think `new` is doing or what `instance.toString()` is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of the instantiation is done by the framework, so you would rarely need to instantiate the classes manually. However, you would still instantiate your own support classes when the need arises.

Answer (score 1):

There is something behind the scene. You can't see all the magic.

Objects are created actually, not by you, but superclasses.